# Tips for golfing in Arturo

Tags: code-golf, tips

Arturo is a bytecode-compiled/interpreted, garbage-collected general-purpose language filling a role similar to JavaScript, Python and Ruby. It is centered around the concept of blocks, which hold code just as easily as data. It uses fixed-arity prefix syntax and emphasizes the procedural and functional paradigms.

What general tips do you have for golfing in Arturo? I'm looking for ideas that are specific to Arturo (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

- [Official website](https://arturo-lang.io/)
- [Documentation](https://arturo-lang.io/documentation/)
- [Playground](https://arturo-lang.io/playground) (online Arturo interpreter)

Answer (score 3):

## Converting integers to strings and vice versa

Instead of

```arturo
to :integer s
```

use Arturo's eval function:

```arturo
do s
```

Instead of

```arturo
to :string n
```

use string interpolation:

```arturo
~"|n|"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Don't use .with:

All [iterators](https://arturo-lang.io/documentation/library/iterators/) in Arturo can take a `.with:` [attribute label](https://arturo-lang.io/documentation/language/#attributeLabel) that lets you assign the index of the iteration to a variable. For instance:

```arturo
loop.with:'i[33 95 7]'n[print~"Index: |i|, Value: |n|"]
```

```
Index: 0, Value: 33
Index: 1, Value: 95
Index: 2, Value: 7
```

However, you can always save a byte by declaring your own index variable and incrementing it manually:

```arturo
i:0loop[33 95 7]'n[print~"Index: |i|, Value: |n|"'i+1]
```

And in the best-case scenario, you don't need to use variables at all. Abuse Arturo's (hidden?) stack instead:

```arturo
0loop[33 95 7]'n[print~"Index: |<=|, Value: |n|"1+]
```

Here, we place 0 on top of the stack, duplicate it with `<=`, and increment it with `1+`.

Answer (score 1):

## Shortening ranges

Consider the following function that finds the sum of squares from 1 to n.

```arturo
$->n[∑map 1..n'x->x^2]
```

You might think this is as short as we can go, since removing the space causes `map1` which is a valid, albeit undefined word name. However, we can remove the space by realizing the symbol `..` (range) can go in the prefix position!

```arturo
$->n[∑map..1n'x->x^2]
```

Since words can't start with numbers, `1n` gets parsed as `[1 n]` instead of `[1n]`. So `..1n` is equivalent to `1..n` and `range 1 n`. But is this really as short as we can go? No, it isn't! In Arturo, you may iterate over numbers themselves with the meaning `1..n`. So

```arturo
$->n[∑map n'x->x^2]
```

is equivalent to the above. Finally, we can shorten this even more by using fat-arrow notation:

```arturo
$=>[∑map&'x->x^2]
```

This causes `&` to become the input parameter. Since it's a symbol instead of the word `n`, it can butt up against its surroundings no problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Consider outputting strings via the clipboard

`clip s` sets the clipboard to string `s`. As long as you're outputting a string all at once, this can save a byte over `print s` and function return (which are tied in length). [Outputting via the clipboard is allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11661/97916).

For example,

```arturo
clip~"It's |now\year| already, folks, go home." ; clipboard
print~"It's |now\year| already, folks, go home." ; stdout
$=>[~"It's |now\year| already, folks, go home."] ; function return
```